# Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)

Tags: python-3.x, pylint, docstring

I am running below the addition of two numbers in jupyter

```py
'''
This program `summationoftwonumbers` and displays their results
'''

A = 1

B = 5

print('Sum of Numbers:',A+B)
```

It is running fine giving an output as `"Sum of Numbers: 6"`

But when running a file by using PyLint, `summationoftwonumber.ipynb` gives the below errors.

```bash
summationoftwonumbers.ipynb:1:0: C0114: Missing module docstring (missing-module-docstring)
summationoftwonumbers.ipynb:1:0: W0104: Statement seems to have no effect (pointless-statement)
```

I do not understand why this is happening.

Comment: It would be nice if you provide a code fence.

Answer (score 1):

It's that you used quotes to write a comment, which in some cases creates a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/). Python is warning you that the statement has no effect in your program. To get rid of the warning you could rewrite the line:

```
''' This program summationoftwonumbers and displays their results '''
```

as a normal comment:

```
# This program summationoftwonumbers and displays their results
```

Comment: I think that is not issue  tried as you said  but same errors are coming
Note: My intention want to work with docstrings